# Change language of entire React Native App

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have a react native application in which the default language is English. I have a profile page in which the user can change the language from English to another language. And when the user saves the language change, the language including the title, drawer navigation names all should be changed to the user chosen language. How we can implement this functionality in react native?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use this package: https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n

Once installed all you have to do is to define your locale files, for example:

```
// src/i18n/locales/en.js
export default {  
  greeting: 'Hi!'
};

// src/i18n/locales/es.js
export default {  
  greeting: 'Hola!'
};

// src/i18n/locales/jp.js
export default {  
  greeting: 'Konichiwa!'
};
```

Then import those files and setup the configuration for i18n support like this:

```
// src/i18n/index.js
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';
import en from './locales/en';
import es from './locales/es'; 
import jp from './locales/jp';  

I18n.fallbacks = true;

I18n.translations = {
  en,
  es,
  jp,
};

export default I18n;
```

And finally use it in your components like this:

```
import I18n from 'src/i18n';

class Demo extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Text>{I18n.t('greeting')}</Text>
    )
  }
}
```

By default it will use the device's locale, but if you want to overwrite that. For example when the user has device with a Spanish locale, but want to use Japanese, you can do something like this:

```
I18n.locale = 'jp';
```

Whenever you call `I18n.t('greeting')` it will render `Konichiwa!`. From now on, you will always need to use `I18n.t` to render any text in your app.

The main issue with this library is the fact that you don't know which keys are still in use once your app grows, managing all your translations is super challenging, I'd recommend you to use a tool like LinguiJS for that: https://bleext.com/post/translating-your-product-into-multiple-languages

Comment: Can I write I18n.locale = 'jp'; as an action to a click event? For e.g. if I want to give the user a way to change the app's language from a list of available languages?

Comment: This library is deprecated in favor of react native languages https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-languages

Comment: i need redux or mobx to store the user settings in such case right ?

Comment: In settings page, if i change the language it does not change the language for already opened routes:(. Anyone facing this issue?

Comment: @Johncy I have faced the same issue. You need to use redux for that. Do you maybe have any better solution?

Comment: If we use redux, we have to connect it to all components and then change the `i18n.locale` variable whenever language changes on settings page.Right? Even though i did in that way, it will not change your *header titles*. We have to manually set header title for navigationOptions whenever i18n.locale changes. So i have restarted whole app using [react-native-restart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-restart).

Comment: When I am changing locale manually , it’s not changing drawer item and opened screen content. What can I do ?

Answer (score 3):

you can install i18n package from this link : https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n

Now, in every part you need to make changes in your language just import I18n to js file:

```
import I18n from "react-native-i18n";
```

and use bottom code in onpress button

```
I18n.locale = "en"; // Language desired
```

Comment: i used your solution and it worked perfect. now there is only one problem when i close app.then restart my app language change again to English.not showing language that already selected.

Comment: is there any idea how to do multi language when locales comes from backend server using api?

Comment: me too looking for the same scenario, can anyone let u know how to achieve as @PrajapatiJigar asked.

Comment: @Lucifer_Lat try to store data in `AsyncStorage`