# Application with multi language selection

Tags: react-native

I am looking for the suggestion. I am a newbie in react-native mobile application. I want to build a simple application where user can select the language: English or Japanese. Based on the language selection my page content should be changed.

Any suggestion or tutorial links that I can follow.

Comment: you can call web service by using definition and dictionary

Comment: chech this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638444/change-language-of-entire-react-native-app

Comment: if the text is static then you can use string.xml to store your values

Comment: @danish: nowadys we have json for that ;)

Answer (score 2):

We're developing a ReactNative app where app language is based on device selected language, with this 3rd party lib : https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization

You can also use https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n as suggested in comment SO link, it seems quite similar...

Answer (score 2):

First of all look into i18n in general and especially with react, here is a good [example](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/setting-up-internationalization-in-react-from-start-to-finish-6cb94a7af725).

In React you could use react-intl together with babel..

You could use a json file as a dictionary for each language and put them as static assets in your project folder, i.E.:

en.json: {"keyword":"translation"}

```
{ 
 "welcomeText":"Welcome",
 "homeBtn":"Home",
 "backBtn":"Back",
 "titleAbout": "About us",
 ....
 ...
 ..
 .
}
```

and then call it like:

```
   <h1>{I18n.t('titleAbout')}</h1>
```

Obviously you need the user to select a language on login or at a later stage inside the app and store it somewhere (local storage per session, in the users-db etc.) as the preferred language and pass it to your react-tranlate module.